# Sql not returning columns metadata when the actual values are null

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-columns

I have an issue in information link SQL query which joins multiple tables where some dynamic column names are returned. They are stored in `label` and `value` attribute of the below query. Please note we had certain fields in the database which when null doesn't appear as column in the output. For e.g a field `test1` in the database has all values `null` then `test1` doesn't get returned. However, even if a single value (row) of `test1` has some data, I see `test1` in the output. The requirement is always have this field in the output irrespective of whether it has the data for not. Please see the query below and point out what is causing issue.

```
SELECT
   I1."item_uid" AS "ITEMUID",
   I1."item_reference_uid" AS "ITEMREFERENCEUID",
   w2."workflow_abbrv" AS "STATUS",
   s3."label" AS "LABEL",
   s3."value" AS "VALUE",
   a4."active_status_desc" AS "ACTIVESTATUSDESC",
   I5."item_reference_uid" AS "PARENTID",
   I5."item_desc_display" AS "PARENTDESCDISPLAY"
FROM
   ("synaptica"."dbo"."sub_elements" s3 LEFT OUTER JOIN "synaptica"."dbo"."ITEMS_REPOSITORY" I1 ON I1."item_uid" = s3."item_uid") 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN("synaptica"."dbo"."ITEMS_REPOSITORY" I5 
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN(select "syndetic_key_item", "rel_type_abbrv", "syndetic_rel_item" from "synaptica"."dbo"."SYNDETIC_NETWORK" s55
   left join "synaptica"."dbo"."RELATIONSHIP_TYPES" R66 ON S55."syndetic_rel_type" = R66."rel_type_uid"
    where (R66."rel_type_abbrv" = 'PhysParent' or R66."rel_type_abbrv" is null))S6

ON 

I5."item_uid" = S6."syndetic_rel_item") ON I1."item_uid" = S6."syndetic_key_item",
   "synaptica"."dbo"."workflow_types" w2,
   "synaptica"."dbo"."active_statuses" a4,
   "synaptica"."dbo"."OBJECT_CLASSES" O8,
   "synaptica"."dbo"."approval_statuses" a9

WHERE
   (I1."item_active_status" = a4."active_status_uid")
   AND (a9."approval_status_uid" = I1."item_approval_status")
   AND (I1."item_object_class" = O8."object_class_uid")
   AND (I1."item_workflow" = w2."workflow_uid")
   AND ((left(O8."object_class_abbrv",
   7) = left(?VER,
   7)))
   AND (s3."label" <> 'CLS360_OBJECT_ID')
   AND (RIGHT(O8."object_class_abbrv",
   10) = 'PHYS CLASS')
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: The database is Sql-Server.